# HMVC Module Error - Undefined property: model

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc

So I'm getting the error: Undefined property: badge_progress::$bp_model.

I don't understand what's going on. Here is my code:

Controller:

```
<?php
// Badge Progress Module

class badge_progress extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('bp_model');

        $data['dotpoints'] = $this->bp_model->dotpoints('1');
        $this->load->view('bp_view', $data);
    }
}

?>
```

Model:

```
<?php
class bp_model extends CI_Model {

    function dotpoints($badge_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM course_topic_dotpoints WHERE badge_id = ".$badge_id);

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Try `badge_progress extends MX_Controller` and see if that helps. Are you using this?: https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home

Comment: Yes I am. If I use MX_Controller, it gives me this error: "Cannot redeclare class CI in ..."

Comment: It sounds like you may have HMVC set up wrong. Are you using any `MY_*` classes in `/core` that don't belong to HMVC? Do other models/modules work fine?

Comment: I have 2 files in the /core folder, named MY_Loader.php and MY_Router.php. Honestly, I'm not entirely sure what they're for. I have not got any modules working yet, this is my first attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Ah fixed it! Didn't realise that the main controllers (controllers outside of the module directory) also needed to be extending "MX_Controller" instead of "CI_Controller".

Comment: Isn't that the [first thing I suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746103/hmvc-module-error-undefined-property-model/9746425#comment12398233_9746103)? What did you have to do specifically, can you elaborate on this answer?

Comment: Well yes, but I also put it into the other controllers outside of my modules folder, which I didn't realise I had to do.

Comment: Your other controllers can be full or parse errors and it won't matter because they wouldn't get loaded. There must be something else you did or something you haven't fully explained.

Comment: Nope, I was pretty thorough in monitoring the changes that I made before it worked, and that was it.

Answer (score 0):

Class names *must* begin with an uppercase letter.

`class Badge_progress extends...`

`class Bp_model extends...`

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

### update:

You shouldn't have the logic you need as a function in your constructor. Create a separate function to process the dotpoints stuff.

```
<?php
// Badge Progress Module

class Badge_progress extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('bp_model');

    }

    function dotpoints()
    {
        $data['dotpoints'] = $this->bp_model->dotpoints('1');
        $this->load->view('bp_view', $data);
    }
}
```

Also, you are missing the constructor in your model. Check out those links I posted earlier...

Comment: I changed them both, but now the error just capitalises them.

Comment: Yep. For some reason I couldn't separate the code sections in the post.

Comment: Great point, hehe. I fixed that up, but it is still spitting out the same error... hmm

Comment: Of course you can have logic in the constructor. In addition, you don't need a constructor if all it does is call the parent constructor, and all CI_Model's constructor does is a `log_message('Model instantiated.')`

Comment: Yeah I noticed that I didn't actually need to put a constructor in my model. Do you know what might be going wrong Madmartigan?

Comment: Let me know if anyone finds anything - I need to solve this quickly.

Comment: @Madmartigan I meant in the way he had it--to be called as a function. It says in the user guide for both models and controllers to "Make sure your class extends the base...". I thought it was as important for the models as controllers to get necessary functionality. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: @Madmartigan also, and sorry to ask here, but know any good CI'rs in CT looking for work?